# Is it a good idea to expose internet facing Azure hosted cloud service (PaaS) using service bus endpoints (using service registry)?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, service-discovery

We are  planning to move our on site services to cloud as PaaS. most of the service might be internet facing. One of the feature we have in our platform is called "Discovery". we were looking into different ways we can discover service in Azure.

Is Service bus's service registry a right option?

1. Is it a good idea to expose all the internet facing platform services hosted by Azure (PaaS) to have endpoint exposed via service bus too. The main goal of doing this to make endpoint dynamically discoverable. But then we worry about double hops for every service call ([Service Bus Endpoint --> Relay --> Actual Endpoint]). Is this a concern?
2. Is there any other way to make services discoverable  in Azure?

-PPT